# Can a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox be temporarily locked?

Tags: c#, combobox

I was wondering whether I can temporarily lock the dropdown list in a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox to its current value programmatically.

The other way aroung (unlock it) would also be useful for logic-bound applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set its "Enabled" property to false until its necessary.

Comment: Perfect! I think you've beaten @Dennis by a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx) property:

```
myCombobox.Enabled = false;
```

?